# Why clickhouse have both WHERE and PREWHERE constructs?

Tags: clickhouse

I'm reading the documentation and just curious about next:

PREWHERE is like an optimized form of WHERE, which reads only necessary data before filtering and then with this information reads all of the actual data for the user.

The question is why two keywords exist? It seems irrational to use WHERE instead of PREWHERE whenever it's possible. Is there any cases when the usage of WHERE is the better choice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PREWHERE is an optimization that is applied automatically even you write WHERE in query. Separate keyword allows to manually tune this optimizer behaviour if you know what you are doing.

Comment: Could you please give concrete examples when WHERE is better than PREWHERE?

Comment: Let's say: table with users who registered on the website sorted by registration time. Each row contains the gender of the user. WHERE genger='m' would be much more efficient that PREWHERE gender='m'.